# Rails way for a simple join with multiple columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What's the rails way to run following query? I found answers in which all columns are being fetched by not selected one. Example query given below:

```
select e.id, e.title, u.first_name,u.picture from events e
inner join users u 
on e.created_by = u.id
where u.id = 2
```

My model given below:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to:user
end
```

**UPDATE** I tried following which infact formed a query but it gives another error:

```
@event = Event.joins(' INNER JOIN users on users.id = events.created_by')
```

> no implicit conversion of String into Integer

And it gives in template on following line:

```
<h3><strong><%= @event["id"] %></strong></h3>
```

Comment: after you update: @event is an array, not a hash (regardless of if you only have one record in it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Event.joins(:users).where("users.id = 2").select('events.id, events.title, users.first_name, users.picture')
```

Comment: It is not working because it's not joining on `id` but on `events.created_by`. I tried this but giving type conversion error for `event.id`

`@event = Event.joins(' INNER JOIN users on users.id = events.created_by')`

p.s: Qs also updated

Comment: The join I made returns the query `SELECT "events".* FROM "events" INNER JOIN users on users.id = events.created_by` but in template I am getting: **no implicit conversion of String into Integer**